# How to make streamed PDF merging without memory consumption?

Tags: pdf, memory, itext, pdfbox, pdftk

I need to merge many small pdf files to one big pdf (~200G). And I can't find library/tool that can do it without eating all my memory.

I watched to itext, pdfbox, pdftk. But seems that all of them store file in memory. According to pdf file structure it should be very easy sequentially take input documents streams and write to result file, keeping in memory only xref table.

Code I used to test iText. With every next file it consumes more and more memory:

```
public static void MergePDFs(String[] fileNames, String targetPdf) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(targetPdf);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
    PdfReader reader = null;
    document.open();
    for (String file : fileNames) {
        reader = new PdfReader(file);
        pdf.addDocument(reader);
        pdf.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
    document.close();
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: PDFBox can use scratch files, see `public void mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting memUsageSetting)`. As a tool, try pdfsam which is based on a PDFBox fork.

Comment: IText has multiple ways to construct pdf readers and writers which have different memory usages. Thus: what have you tried?

Comment: @mkl for the specific use case of files in the gigabyte-terabyte size, none of the PDF libraries can do it in one go without using a special strategy. This is a known issue.

Comment: @mkl added code to question

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Yes. But even if doing it in groups, one can and should optimize memory usage.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr tried to merge two 14Gb files with PDFMergerUtility with MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly() set, but anyway PDFBox consumed 13Gb RAM. It not looks like streaming merge

Comment: Then please try pdfsam. I used it successfully a week ago when I had to split a 1GB file. (Although I hadn't tried with any memory settings on PDFBox)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr checked pdfsam for merging my 14Gb files. It just gave OutOfMemoryError after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to merge in groups of 10 files, then merge the intermediate files. Take as many intermediate steps as needed. For example:

- Step 0: 1000 files of 1 page
- Step 1: 100 files of 10 pages
- Step 2: 10 files of 100 pages
- Step 3: 1 file of 1000 pages

There is no fixed rule, I say 10 but maybe the optimal solution for you is per 8 or per 14, you will have to experiment.

In theory, you could even run the intermediate steps in parallel on different machines, which could speed up the merging significantly, at the expense of needing more hardware.

My answer is generic, and will work for any pdf library, but at iText Software we have done the research that shows that this strategy is faster and less memory consuming.

Comment: anyway in final I'll need to merge two large files. Tried to merge two 14Gb pdfs with iText passing partial=true to PdfReader and got 12Gb memory consumed

Comment: But does it throw an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: No, iText did the merge. But eventually I will need to merge 140Gb files and 120Gb RAM memory consumption is unacceptable

Comment: This is because iText tries to merge files in a smart way, by reusing objects that are already in the file, instead of keeping multiple identical copies of the same objects. This usually results in smaller files. To be able to do that, the objects must be kept _somewhere_, and that results in memory usage.

Comment: I use PdfCopy class, not PdfSmartCopy. I think it shouldn't do this technique

Comment: My apologies, you are absolutely right about the difference between Copy and SmartCopy.

Comment: I don't see how this could work, and I know for a fact it won't work with PDFSharp or Aspose, at least. Every library I've come across needs all of the output PDF contents to be in memory at the time of saving.  The PDF standard does allow for efficient appending but I've yet to come across a .NET library that uses this option.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, I don't work there anymore and I have zero interest in answering any questions about that piece of software.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I know the feeling ;)